# how to make website compatible with all browser

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, browser

I am developing website with ASP.Net and already create a pop up Calendar where it is work successfully in Internet Explorer..
Bbut it work different in chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function asdf() {
            var div = document.getElementById('<%=Div2.ClientID %>');
            if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
                div.style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                div.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

and its code for image calendar and the calendar itself

```
<img alt="Pilih Tanggal" src="images/calendar.png" style="position:absolute;" onclick="javascript:asdf();" /> 
            <div id="Div2" runat="server" style="position:absolute; float:left;"  > 
                    <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar3" style="position:absolute;" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC" 
                    BorderColor="#FFCC66" BorderWidth="1px" DayNameFormat="FirstTwoLetters" 
                    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#663399" Height="173px" 
                    ShowGridLines="True" Width="225px"
                    OnSelectionChanged = "Calendar3_SelectionChanged" 
                    ToolTip="Pilih Tanggal Log File Yang Akan Dilihat" 
                    onvisiblemonthchanged="Calendar3_VisibleMonthChanged">
                    <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" Font-Bold="True" />
                    <SelectorStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" />
                    <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="White" />
                    <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#CC9966" />
                    <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                    <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" Height="1px" />
                    <TitleStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="9pt" 
                    ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                </asp:Calendar>
            </div>
```

can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use jquery and jquery plugins to prevent alot of work and pain.

Try this example:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/jQuery-UI-DatePicker-Calendar-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: my workplace doesnt give internet connection and i cant plug in usb there, thats why i cant use jquery.. any solution ? thank youuu